# Function parameters iterate over a csv file values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, function, csv

i have this function

```
def audience(lat,lon,ids):
buff = buff_here(lat,lon)[-1]
count_visitas = []
for visitas in glob.glob(path): ......

df = pd.DataFrame(count_visitas, columns =['Visitas'])
df.to_csv(f'output/visitas_simi_{ids}.csv', index = False)
return count_visitas
```

I can't post the complete code here due to work issues, but it's works perfectly fine if i pass this parameters

```
audience(-33.51133739,-70.7558227,'CL0008')
```

Now, i have this [csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0dPs.jpg) and want to iterate over the rows of lat, lon and id as a parameter of the function. Any help, please? :c

Comment: How are you trying to pass the variables from the csv row?

Comment: yep, i want to pass the parameters lat, lon, ids from the csv rows :c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to bring the csv in with `csv.DictReader` and then you can call the desired columns:

```
csv_file = csv.DictReader(open(file, 'rU'))
for row in csv_file:
    count_visitas = audience(row['lat'],row['lon'],row['ids'])
```

Comment: Thanks!! works perfectly,<3

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
import csv

with open("names.csv", "r") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    for line in csv_reader:
        lat = line["first_name"]
        lon = line["last_name"]
        ids = line["email"]

        audience(lat, lon, ids)
```